# Dynamic select options unique to their parent using underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

This is my code fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/ost9area/

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I created three arrays for the data:

```
filterFields = {
    "group.name": "Group name",
    "group.effective_status": "Group status",
    "subgroup.name": "Subgroup name",
    "subgroup.effective_status": "Subgroup status",
    "person.name": "Person name",
    "person.effective_status": "Person status",
}

filterOperators = {
    "name": {
        "CONTAIN": "Contains",
        "NOT_CONTAIN": "Doesn't contain"
    },
    "effective_status": {
        "status.IN": "is",
        "status.NOT_IN": "is not"
    }
}
filterStatuses = {
    "group": {
        "ACTIVE": "Active",
        "PAUSED": "Paused"
    },
    "subgroup": {
        "ACTIVE": "Active",
        "PAUSED": "Paused",
        "GROUP_PAUSED": "Group Paused"
    },
    "person": {
        "ACTIVE": "Active",
        "PAUSED": "Paused",
        "GROUP_PAUSED": "Grpup Paused",
        "SUBGROUP_PAUSED": "Subgroup Paused"
    }
}
```

The concept is, when the `name` is selected in the first field, the `contains` is selected in second and textbox should appear in the third. However, when `effective_status` is selected in the first field, the `status` is selected in second field and third is also select menu. I did that, and I also managed to make the multiple conditions there. But, only first of the boxes work. I can make all the boxes work, by setting up individual `id` for each field dynamically.

I'm not sure if that's the right way to go. I already have 22 lines of javascript and 3 underscore templates just to do that. I'm looking for a guide to do this the right way. Also, please keep in mind that when `Save Changes` is clicked, I'm planning to send the data to the root page (before popup).

How can we handle conditions like this properly? When an unlimited number of fields can be added, and one field is manipulated by another.